# What is Proper Format for a Numbered List (Series) within a Sentence

Tags: lists

I know there a lot of ways to format a numbered series or list within a sentence.  My question pertains to the proper use of parentheses when writing the list continually without hitting the return key between list items. Specifically, should the numbers be written as (1), (2), (3), etc., or is 1), 2), 3), etc. acceptable?

Comment: Use pairs. http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/parentheses.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that numbered list without hitting the return is not a really acceptable good thing per se.

However, I believe that is a common thing in academic papers, probably because there are space constraints. I have read several papers where that happens, but always as (1) (2) (3), never in other ways.

[This link](http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2008/09/grammar-workshop-how-to-present-a-numbered-list-in-a-sentence.html) may help you.

Comment: Note that the linked blog post provides a personal opinion, not the law of the land. It is from someone with a strong professional background in editing, but nevertheless, it is far from the only correct approach to punctuation and enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

This, like most questions about punctuation, capitalization, and spacing, is a matter of style. There is no single universally correct presentation, nor on when and how to punctuate preceding or following text. You should adhere to the advice of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, to your preferred [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579). If not covered therein, professional standards demand only consistency; choose a system, and stick with it in all your writing.

For what it's worth, Chicago, AP, and APA agree that letters or numbers, however capitalized or punctuated, should only be used for inline or *run-in* lists when absolutely necessary to separate complex items. See the [APA Style blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/02/lists-part-1-parallelism.html) and the [Chicago Style Q&A](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/VerticalListsBullets.html) for some coverage.